# How to read a recursive algorithm

Tags: recursive-algorithms

It is a newbie question and I hope it is the right section. I am counting the number of steps an algorithm requires to complete its calculation. 
Let's consider a factorization algorithm expressed in F# code:

```
let rec factorial n =
    if n = 0 then 1
    else n * factorial (n - 1)
```

If `n = 0`, it returns `1`, otherwise it returns the multiplication between `n` and `n - 1`.

Now, suppose we feed the algorithm with `n = 4`. My question is: how the algorithm actually proceeds?

```
f1(4) = 4*3*2*1 = 24
f2(4) = 4*3 + 3*2 + 2*1 + 1*1 + 3*2 + 2*1 + 1*1 = 24
```

I think it is `f2`, because every loop of the algorithm calculates a single multiplication for a total of 7 multiplications and 6 additions, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: This is a good resource for computing the big-Oh for recursive functions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm in no place sums things, so it surely is **not** f2!

Notice that inside your function `factorial` you call the function itself! Again! Let us write down the whole process, where each line we simplify a new bit

`factorial 4
4 * (factorial(4 - 1))
4 * (factorial(3))
4 * (3 * (factorial(3 - 1)))
4 * (3 * (factorial(2)))
4 * (3 * (2 * (factorial(2 - 1))))
4 * (3 * (2 * (factorial(1))))
4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * (factorial(1 - 1)))))
4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * (factorial(0)))))
4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * 1)))
4 * (3 * (2 * 1))
4 * (3 * 2)
4 * 6
24`

Comment: I was actually wondering where were the additions. So, does it works only with multiplications?

Comment: @Worice your algorithm uses only multiplications, but you could create other algorithms to do other things that would use additions or subtractions or any other operation in this recursive manner.

Comment: Ok, then if I got it correctly, can I say that your example consists of 4 multiplications (4*3*2*1) and 4 subtractions, each subtraction producing the n - 1 for the successive step?

Comment: @Worice yes that is right.

Comment: Ok, now I definitely have a better grasp on the issue, thank you very much!

Comment: @Worice no problem. when you do not know what is going on, write down a simple example

Comment: Sorry of course, I was applying your suggestions on an exercise.